# Swift test --filter seems to exclude everything when actually running tests

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, quick-nimble

I have a swift library compiled with SwiftPM and I have two `testTarget`s declared in my `Package.swift`. I would like to be able to run these two test targets independently in my CI, so I have been trying to run something like:

`swift test --filter='unitTests'
swift test --filter='integrationTests'`

When I run without `--filter`, I see 4 unit tests run, with 1 failure; and 1 integration test, with 1 failure. However, these `--filter` commands result in 1 passing unit test, and 0 integration tests, running.

But when I add `--list` to those commands, all the appropriate tests appear in the list. I can't find any reason these tests would be excluded when using `--filter`.

Am I missing something about the behavior of `--filter` here?

Answer (score 0):

The `--filter` option works on test names (and not the type of test). SwiftPM uses regex on test names with the given input and runs the matching tests.

Comment: That is what I expect, in particular `unitTests` and `integrationTests` are the names of my test targets and therefore they appear as the prefix to my test names, as they appear in `--list`, like `unitTests.firstBehaviorSpec; integrationTests.complexBehaviorSpec`. So this behavior still surprises me.